# pivot_wider/spread only a subset of levels from a column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape

I want to reshape just a subset of levels/values within a single column to wide, but leave selected levels in the original column.

In this example data, the 'rice' and 'beans' values in the food column don't have a "type" characteristic.
I want to keep the original column "food" and its levels "rice" and "beans" while pivoting the other values to wide.

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
df<-tibble(index=sample(1:5, 10, replace=TRUE),
            food=c(rep('fruit', 4),rep('meat', 4), 'rice', 'beans'),
            type=c('apple', 'apple', 'banana', 'banana', 'steak', 'steak', 't-bone', 't-bone', NA, NA))

# A tibble: 10 x 3
   index food  type  
   <int> <chr> <chr> 
 1     1 fruit apple 
 2     4 fruit apple 
 3     1 fruit banana
 4     2 fruit banana
 5     5 meat  steak 
 6     3 meat  steak 
 7     2 meat  t-bone
 8     3 meat  t-bone
 9     3 rice  NA    
10     1 beans NA
```

The desired output would be like this:

```
output<-structure(list(index = c(1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 3L), fruit = c("apple", 
"banana", "apple", "banana", NA, NA, NA), meat = c(NA, NA, NA, 
"t-bone", "steak", "steak", "t-bone"), food = c("beans", NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "rice", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

output
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  index fruit  meat   food 
  <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1     1 apple  NA     beans
2     1 banana NA     NA   
3     4 apple  NA     NA   
4     2 banana t-bone NA   
5     5 NA     steak  NA   
6     3 NA     steak  rice 
7     3 NA     t-bone NA
```

I could do it manually by moving the 'rice' and 'beans' values to the 'type' column and creating a corresponding 'food' level in the 'food' column. Apart from the laborious and non-systematic transformation, i got an unnexpected output, with duplicated 'beans' and 'rice' values:

```
df1%>%mutate(type=coalesce(type, food),
             food=replace(food, type %in% c('rice', 'beans'), 'food'))%>%
        pivot_wider(id_cols = index, names_from = c(food), values_from = c(type))%>%
        unnest
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  index fruit  meat   food 
  <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1     1 apple  NA     beans
2     1 banana NA     beans ###<-
3     4 apple  NA     NA   
4     2 banana t-bone NA   
5     5 NA     steak  NA   
6     3 NA     steak  rice 
7     3 NA     t-bone rice ###<-
```

I wonder if there is simpler and safer way to do it on-the-fly with pivot_wider

Comment: Maybe you give a little bit mor context what you are trying to achieve here. If there are two fruits with index 1 and one food with index 1, why would beans appear only on the row with fruit apple? What would happen if there are two fruits and two meats with the same index? Would you expect 2 rows (with which fruit/meat combination) or rather 4 rows with all combinations?

Comment: Thank you @MarkusN, for going through the question and identifying it still needs some clarification. I hope I can do that eventually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may do this with `coalesce`and `replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
    mutate(type = coalesce(type, food), 
           food =  replace(food, food == type, 'food'),
            rn = rowid(index, food)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = food, values_from = type) %>% 
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
  index fruit  meat   food 
  <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
1     1 apple  <NA>   beans
2     4 apple  <NA>   <NA> 
3     1 banana <NA>   <NA> 
4     2 banana t-bone <NA> 
5     5 <NA>   steak  <NA> 
6     3 <NA>   steak  rice 
7     3 <NA>   t-bone <NA>
```

Comment: Is the `rn=rowid()` the step that eliminates the 'duplicate' beans and rice I got in the last column? I see you and ronak both used a similar approach

Comment: @GuedesBF yes `rowid` from `data.table` does that without having to do an extra group by step

Comment: @GuedesBF For duplicate row indexing, it is the standard method i.e. group_by/row_number() or `rowid`

Comment: Ok, thank you. As @MarkusN commented, I must clarify some things in the question, which I will do eventually, but you guys showed I was not all that for from the answer. This duplicate row indexing methods are awesome, thanks again.

Comment: I was hoping i could do all that inside the call to pivot_wider, but it seems to be a very specifical situation for which there is no solution besides manually changing values beforehand

Comment: @GuedesBF the issue is that your column values needs swapped and pivot_wider takes only arguments.  If it was just the value column, it could be sorted in `values_fn`, but this was not the case

Answer (score 1):

You can use -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(type = if_else(food %in% c('rice', 'beans'), food, type), 
         food = replace(food, food %in% c('rice', 'beans'), 'food')) %>%
  group_by(index, food) %>%
  mutate(row  = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = food, values_from = type) %>%
  select(-row)
  
#  index fruit  meat   food 
#  <int> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>
#1     1 apple  NA     beans
#2     4 apple  NA     NA   
#3     1 banana NA     NA   
#4     2 banana t-bone NA   
#5     5 NA     steak  NA   
#6     3 NA     steak  rice 
#7     3 NA     t-bone NA
```